# Q: PDDL doesn't compile problem and domain

Tags: planning, pddl

I don't know why it doesn't work. here is my code:

#### Domain

```
(define (domain tren_mover)
    (:requirements :adl)
    (:predicates
       (conectado ?x ?y)
       (en ?x ?y)
       (movil ?x)
    )
    (:action mover
        :parameters (?tren ?origen ?destino)
        :precondition 
        (and 
          (movil ?tren)
          (en ?origen ?destino)
          (conectado ?origen ?destino)
        )
        :effect 
        (and 
           (en ?tren ?destino)
           (not (en ?tren ?origen))
        )
    )
)
```

#### Problem

```
(define (problem tren_en_movimiento)
    (:domain tren_mover)
    (:objects
        T - tren
        F1- Fábrica1
        F2 - Fábrica2
        A - almacén
        P - puerto
    )
    (:init
        (en puerto tren)
        (mover tren)
        (conectado A P)
        (conectado P F2)
        (conectado F2 F1)
        (conectado F1 A)
        (conectado A F1)
        (conectado F1 F2)
        (conectado F2 P)
        (conectado P A)
    )
    (:goal (and
                (en F1 T)
           )
    )

)
```

The **Error** message that appears is:

```
Failed to parse the problem -- invalid syntax (, line 37)

/tmp/solver_planning_domains_tmp_4C4oEmiiY8B3Q/domain.pddl:
syntax error in line 16, '':
domain definition expected
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several logical and syntactical mistakes in your code:

##### Logical

`(en ?origen ?destino)` how can you put two positions in the same place! it should be the `tren` who has to be in the origin position.

##### Syntactical

1. The `objects` in the problem, you have to understand the difference between `types` and `objects`, you are mixing between them!
2. There is a typo in the initial state, you are using `mover` instead of `movil`.
3. in the `goal`, you are using `and()` which is not needed, and moreover causes an error as you don't have two predicates to combine!

### Domain

```
(define (domain tren_mover)
    (:requirements :adl)
    (:predicates
       (conectado ?x ?y)
       (en ?x ?y)
       (movil ?x)
    )
    (:action mover
        :parameters (?tren ?origen ?destino)
        :precondition 
        (and 
          (movil ?tren)
          (en ?tren ?origen)
          (conectado ?origen ?destino)
        )
        :effect 
        (and 
           (en ?tren ?destino)
           (not (en ?tren ?origen))
        )
    )
)
```

### Problem

```
(define (problem tren_en_movimiento)
    (:domain tren_mover)
    (:objects tren Fabrica1 Fabrica2 almacen puerto)
    (:init
        (en tren puerto)
        (movil tren)
        (conectado almacen puerto)
        (conectado puerto Fabrica2)
        (conectado Fabrica2 Fabrica1)
        (conectado Fabrica1 almacen)
        (conectado almacen Fabrica1)
        (conectado Fabrica1 Fabrica2)
        (conectado Fabrica2 puerto)
        (conectado puerto almacen)
    )
    (:goal
        (en tren Fabrica1)
    )

)
```

[Solution Test](http://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=usHT2Kqfon)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider including the requirement `:typing` to categorize the parameters used in `predicates and actions`. Due to this error, the `:objects` in the problem file can't be parsed correctly.

Please refer to this link: https://planning.wiki/ref/pddl/requirements#typing
and try to rectify errors.

Also, You can use VS Code plugin available for PDDL to avoid syntax errors and solve the plan. It can be found here: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jan-dolejsi.pddl

Best Regards!